# Remove a view of a class in Xcode

Tags: xcode, view

Hi
Is there a way to remove a view from another view of a specific class?
What I mean I have a view with multiple other views like a scrollview, imageview, tableview and I only want to remove the scrollview. 
I thought the code would be something like this:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.superview.subviews) {

    if ([view.class == [Class UIScrollView]]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But this didn't work. I could work with object at index: but because we don't know what index the scrollview has,so it also won't work.  (I think)

Does someone knows the answer to this problem? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you able to assign an IBOutlet to the UIScrollView in interface builder?

Comment: Yes it's possible. but Isn't there a possible way to not use the IBOutlet?

Comment: Well, it's possible to peel a potato with a spoon but it's easier with a peeler

Comment: ah so how do I solve it with the IBOutlet? (And If I'm not able to assign an IBOutlet? like when the class itself is UIScrollView?) I have 1 scrollview in a view (here I can assign the IBOutlet) but I have also another scrollView, but here I can't assign an IBOutlet) If you know what I mean. (thank you for helping! :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this what you mean?

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.superview.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] ) {
        NSLog(@"class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set an IBOutlet to the subview just call [removeFromSuperview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) on the saved outlet.

(log the outlet to make sure it's set properly if that doesn't work)

(pretty sure that applies to both NSView and UIView)